# while using textbutton adding more space inside container in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have created section heading row for title of sections but when i set true to its showall button, container occupies more padding than it should..how to fix container height even though used showbutton or not..

[image]

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          children: [
       Container(
         color: Colors.red,
           padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
           child: SectionHeading(showButton: true),),

          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: SectionHeading(showButton: false)),


        ],),
      ),
    );
```

code of custom widget SECTIONHEADING

```
class SectionHeading extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool showButton;

  const SectionHeading({Key? key,required this.showButton}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
      Text('Popular Products',style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,),

// i updated here with style of textbutton but still not getting //what i want..still getting unwanted padding 
      if(showButton) TextButton(style: TextButton.styleFrom(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero),onPressed: (){}, child: Text('All')),


    ],);
  }
}
```

Comment: set the Button padding to zero

Comment: not working...showing still same..check i have updated....

Comment: you can wrap the button with sizedbox and give height to the sizedbox

Comment: Does ***[this](https://dartpad.dev/?id=cc80c80e2fe6d84c4d50af2461ac1042)*** help?

Comment: or you can give maxsize to the button

Comment: mandy thats working but i want to give second container size like first container...not first container size like second..hope you understand...even if button is shown container height must b as first container

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(showButton) TextButton(style: TextButton.styleFrom(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero),onPressed: (){}, child: Text('All')),
```

Comment: I tried but nothing changed.....still both container not looking the same